# ESRI Geocoder Service Different Name For Single Line Input

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geocoding, geocoding-service

I have two ArcGIS Geocoding Services but they have different Service Descriptions on **Single Line Address Field:** part

For [This Service](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Locators/SanDiego/GeocodeServer) I have `SingleLine`
[image]

but for [This One](http://map.stjohns.ca/mapsrv/rest/services/CSJ_STREETNAMES_SNOWREMOVAL6/GeocodeServer) it is `Single Line Input`

[image]

Can you please let me know why they are different and How I can configure them on Server or locator side?

Answer (score 2):

This article provides the explanation:

> The singleLineAddressField value for address locators built using the
>   US Address locator style is Single Line Input, whereas composite
>   locators use SingleLine.

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013057